# How to use two paint methods in java? Or outside the basic paint method

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe

How can i create two paint methods?
When i'm trying to use two paint methods on of them is never working.
If that cant be i want to paint outside the basic paint method and i dont know how.
For example:

```
public class test extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                test frame = new test();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
}

public void pp(Graphics g) {
    g.fillRect(250, 100, 100, 100);
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public test() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
}

}
```

Comment: Both these methods, have different responsibilities `(paint and paintComponent)`. In my opinion, first learn the basics of painting, from [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), and then try your hands on this. Dont' `paint` on a top level container, instead delegate this task, to some container, like `JPanel/JComponent`, and paint in it's `paintComponent` method. `paint()` internally will call `paintComponent()` automatically. Moreover, try not to use `AbsolutePositiong`, instead use a relevant `LayoutManager`

Comment: This could help you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html

Comment: Please please *please* read a *complete* guide on object oriented programming. Had you known about methods you would have never had to ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way.

`public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        draw(g);
        draw2(g);
    }`

```
public void draw(Graphics g){
    g.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
}

public void draw2(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(200, 100, 100, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> When i'm trying to use two paint methods on of them is never working.

`paintComponent(...)` is not a method of JFrame. Whenever you attempt to override a method you should use the `@Override` annotation and the compiler will tell you when you attempt to override a method that doesn't exist.

In general, for other Swing components, the `paint(...)` method is responsible for invoking the `paintComponent(...)` method, so you should not override the `paint()` method. See: [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) for more information.

Anyway you should NOT override paint() on a JFrame. Read the whole section on `Performing Custom Painting` from the tutorial link for a working example of how custom painting should be done.